# How to get the list of people in the chat?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I just started a tab project using `Teams Toolkit` on VS 2022 and C#

I couldn't find a way to get list of people in the chat that tab added, or the list of people in the team that tab added.

`TeamsInfo` class seems promising, but all the methods expect `ITurnContext`, which I'm not sure how to get.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to get this info directly using Teams Toolkit (i.e. client side) - you need make a server call to get this info. You can do so either:

1. with a bot (i.e. if you app has / can add a bot as part of the app as well) - see here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#fetch-the-roster-or-user-profile
2. via the Graph API - see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . In this case your app can will require an Azure Application and a consent, either from an admin or a user, or you'd RSC - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent